# Android compass

Tags: android, compass-geolocation

I am currently developing an application that takes the users position and determine which bus stop is closest and then show the departures from that stop on the screen. Now I want to make a compass which points towards that bus stop and I'm not quite sure how to achieve this. Any guidelines would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [First Android App - How to Access the Compass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740228/first-android-app-how-to-access-the-compass)

Answer (score 0):

In the examples for the API, there is one which implements a simple compass. It's comprised of the following classes: CompassActivity, GraphicsActivity and PictureLayout. Is shows a simple needle pointing to magnetic North.

You can use GeomagneticField.get Declination() to give you the variation from true North and thus adjust to make the needle point true North.

Assuming you know 1): your location (myLocation, say), 2): the bus stop's location (stopLocation, say). You can use myLocation.bearingTo(stopLocation) to give you the bearing to the bus stop. All you need do then is to add this bearing to the compensated compass bearing to make the needle point to the bus stop. (The bearing to magnetic North is in event.values[0] in the SensorEventListener)

Answer (score 0):

this is an old question but maybe this will help someone:

I developed a small Helper Class: [Compass Assistant](https://github.com/klein-artur/Simple-Android-Compass-Assistant)

This class provides the heading of the phone relative to north. It has a function to get the bearing between two locations. If you pass the phone´s current location as the first location, you can get the bearing and show it to the user.

Don´t hesitate to ask me or give me feedback for the assistant.